# Unable to switch Java versions by executing script created in a .bat file (Windows)

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I am trying to switch between Java versions (back and forth between v8 and v11) on a Windows 10 computer. I've tried changing my environment variables manually setting JAVA_HOME to v8, however it seems I can't switch out of v11.

[My current System Path Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKVv3.png)

[My current User Path Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM3UH.png)

I've also created .bat scripts to change between Java versions via a command in the Terminal (java8, java11). The .bat scripts are able to execute, however the Java version doesn't change. The .bat script is included in my User Path and System Path variables and the directory is `C\Users\BOL\Java Scripts`.

[My cmd line commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJQXT.png)

[My .bat scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqtY7.png)

Anyone have an idea why I am unable to change between versions? I don't care on how I can switch versions, just want to be able to switch them :)

Comment: Java_home param should be first row of list for path

Comment: So, the %JAVA_HOME%\bin environment variable should be on the first row of both User env vars and System env vars? I tried this with no luck. Or are you saying %JAVA_HOME% should be at the top of these lists?

Comment: I can't prove it because I don't have multiple versions of Java installed, but I suspect that your problem stems from the fact that you're running a batch script from a Powershell window, which causes the script to run as a child process, which means that the environment does not get transferred back to the parent shell. Run the script from a CMD window instead of a Powershell window.

Comment: This should tell you why your change isn't working after each script: run `echo %PATH%` , `where java` and  `where java.exe` before `java -version`, add that to the question. You'll need to clean up your system variables to exclude the multiple Java choices such as oracle javapath. Don't use images for text / scripts, also include them in question.

Comment: @PleasePleasePleaseHelp  i hope this will help you to figure it out. https://java2blog.com/how-to-set-java-path-windows-10/ , if still not works try to move up at the top of list. Because system works with first match.

Comment: Ok, got it working and am now able to switch java versions via the .bat scripts I created! Thank you newuserua_ext and @SomethingDark. After moving the %JAVA_HOME%\bin to the top of the env vars for both User and System and using the Command Prompt instead of Powershell, I'm able to switch between the versions